# Cannot reach the web service from an other pc

Tags: java, web-services, endpoint

I simply publish a web service with the following code in `Java`:

```
    String dbAccessAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:8024/SmartService";
    try {
            if (ep != null && ep.isPublished() == false) {

                ep = Endpoint.publish(dbAccessAddress, new DbAccess());

                logger.info("DbAccess started: " + dbAccessAddress);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("DbAccess failed(" + dbAccessAddress + ")", ex, false);
        }
```

This service works perfectly on **localhost** but when I try to reach the service from an other computer within the local network, i can not connect to it. Timeout occurs.
I also tried with the browser by writing the service wsdl URL but it can not reach the service. Only works locally.
What is the problem?

Comment: Is your server configured to listener on the ip address? not localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address 127.0.0.1 is reserved for the localhost, this means only local connections are possible. You will have to use a ip address from your local network or simply bind to all interfaces, if you want to your service to be accessible in the local network.